# Saving related model objects

Tags: django, django-models

I have two related models (one to many) in my django app and When I do something like this

```
ObjBlog = Blog()
objBlog.name = 'test blog'

objEntry1 = Entry()
objEntry1.title = 'Entry one'

objEntry2 = Entry()
objEntry2.title = 'Entry Two'

objBlog.entry_set.add(objEntry1)
objBlog.entry_set.add(objEntry2)
```

I get an error which says "null value in column and it violates the foreign key not null constraint".

None of my model objects have been saved. Do I have to save the "objBlog" before I could set the entries? I was hoping I could call the save method on objBlog to save it all.

***NOTE: I am not creating a blog engine and this is just an example.***

Comment: This may be informative https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that one of your models has a Foreign Key field which is not nullable.
When you do `objBlog.entry_set.add(objEntry1)` django calls save() on each object.

This is how the `add` method looks like:

```
def add(self, *objs):
    for obj in objs:
        if not isinstance(obj, self.model):
            raise TypeError("'%s' instance expected" % self.model._meta.object_name)
        setattr(obj, rel_field.name, instance)
        obj.save()
add.alters_data = True
```

Comment: so I have to save the blog object before I could save the entry object?

Comment: It gets saved automatically, how do your models look like? Django is probably complaining because there is a FK relation to a model other then `Blog` and `Entry` on one or both of them which can not be null. Actual traceback would be helpful for providing actual help or at least the actual exception.

Comment: I had to save the Blog object first. I guess, I thought Django would save the Blog object first and then save the Entry objects. When I say "save", I do objBlog.save() and then I do this objBlog.entry_set.add(objEntry). Now I know that I have to save the parent object first.